# Если закрыть приложение, но не Activity, то метод OnDestroy() не срабатывает

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sdk, activity

Почему если при открытом `Activity` закрыть приложение, то `OnDestroy` не вызовется. Но если закрыть `Activity`, то он вызывается?

Comment: Вызов `onDestroy` не гарантирован. Его наличие зависит от того, что стало причиной закрытия активности и находится ли она на виду у пользователя. Подробностей не помню, курите документацию))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто. Когда мы закрываем приложение - активити не уничтожается, а переводится в onStop(), так как приложение все еще доступно в панели задач. В это же время нажатие кнопки back уничтожает активити, если поведение back не переопределено. Если вы уберете приложение из списка задач после его закрытия - активити уничтожится. И да. Есть случаи, когда onDestroy не вызывается вообще, но это крайне редкие случаи и связаны со сбоями в работе ОС андроид (чаще всего по нехватке памяти).

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "закрываем приложение"?

Comment: вы так пишите, будто на вызов этого метода можно рассчитывать, а зря.

Comment: Думаю автор вопроса имел ввиду кнопку хоум

Comment: Я вообще не представляю, что такого можно засунуть в onDestroy(), что критически важно к сохранению